# Use jQuery on Event, instead of automatic upload on plugin file-uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this pluging to upload files: https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

But now I starts the upload as soon as you have choosen a file.

See demo http://valums.com/files/2010/file-uploader/demo.htm

Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction so that I disable the auto submission but instead use preferable a jQuery command with a button

something like

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

....Now run start the upload...

});
```

Comment: I looked into the code page briefly, it does not provide any function to initiate a upload, so its not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

It should suffice your requirement through `.uploadifyUpload()`

Don't forget to set `'auto'      : false`

Comment: Thanks, I just found the other one and like the how simple it was, but this script will do.